# How much memory does jProfiler need to analyze a heap dump of size X?

Tags: java, memory, profiling, jprofiler

I have a heap size of X (= 5 giga bytes). How much should I allocate for jprofiler to efficiently analyze this heap?

Comment: Running it with 12 gigs has failed (it got stuck after reading the dump). I'm trying to give it 30 gigs to see how it works.

Comment: Note that I am using the "Calculate retained sizes" option.

Comment: YourKit succeeded in opening the dump without even increasing the default of 512 mb (Though "track GC roots" operation failed even when I increased the RAM to 2 gigs).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to view the heap dump.  It does a much better job in terms of memory requirements for a heap dump of size X because it creates intermediate index files on disk instead of sucking up the whole thing into it's own memory.  Most tools require some multiple N of X to open the heap dump where N is usually >= 2.  Also, make sure to start the Java process that runs MAT or JProfiler in 64-bit if you're going to give them more than 2g of memory.